# getBody still chucks out a "can't call getBody out of null" error even though it isn't null in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

getBody still returns null inside Apps Script, even though I've poked around for errors and debugged most. Another user (who pointed out to me most of the errors) said that getBody, in this code, isn't null. Is this a bug with my code, or Apps Script's?

```
function myFunction() {

var searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult)
Logger.log(searchResult)



while (searchResult !== null) {

searchResult.getElement().asText().setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),"#FF000")

searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult)

}



function highlightProblem() {

var words = ["very","so","totally","really"] 

words.forEach(findText) 

  }


 function onOpen(){
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('everythingisnotfine.avi').addItem('Higlight Words That Make You Sound Like a Dandy', 'higlightProblem').addToUi()
}}
```

Comment: well the error is saying that `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` is null....

Comment: if so, then why exactly?

Comment: I have no clue about google scripts.... maybe a search for `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() returns null` or something similar will turn up reasons why.

Comment: Is this code in script editor of google document? and when you reopen the document do you see menu "everythingisnotfine.avi" in your google document?

Comment: @JackBrown yes, and I don't see the menu pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue was you were using searchResult even before it was defined.

```
var searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult)
```

Since you don't have `searchResult` defined yet, you cannot pass `findText()` a `searchResult` to start from. Once you have first searchResult variable define you can use in the while loop to find the matchs

```
while (searchResult !== null) {
 searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText(very,searchResult)
 }
```

Secondly, you were defining the function `onOpen()` and `highlightProblem()` with the context of `myFunction()` like so

```
function myFunction(){  // <--- Start of my function

 function highlightProblem(){
 }
 function onOpen(){
 }
}                      //<-- End of my function
```

You will need to define each function separately as shown below.

Your final code:

```
function findText(searchString) {
 Logger.log(searchString)
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
 //var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("Copy and paste URL of your doc here")
 var searchResult = doc.getBody().findText(searchString)
 Logger.log(searchResult)
 var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFFF00';
 while (searchResult !== null) {
 searchResult.getElement().asText().setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),style)
 searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText(searchString,searchResult)
 }
}

function highlightProblem() {
 var words = ["very","so","totally","really"] 
 words.forEach(findText)   
}



 function onOpen(){       
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('everythingisnotfine.avi').addItem('Higlight Words That Make You Sound Like a Dandy', 'highlightProblem').addToUi()
    }
```

**Steps to run the code**
1) Copy and paste in script editor as is. Then run the function onOpen() to add custom menus to your document
2) You can run the highlight function from script editor or from the custom menus
3) If you still unable to run it uncomment(remove //) this line and copy and paste URL as mentioned
`//var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("Copy and paste URL of your doc here")`